# how to flip from one view to another view in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I wan't to flip from one view controller to another for that i used following coding on button click

```
-(void)ClicOnLogout {
    LogOutViewController *logOut=[[LogOutViewController alloc]initwithnName:str];  
    logOut.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;  

    [self presentModalViewController:logOut animated:YES];  
}
```

but when i m in logout view controller there is one button but it won't work so can any one give me the proper  solution for it.

Thanx...

Comment: Whats your actual requirement...

Comment: actually i have logout button on one view controller i want to navigated 2nd view using flip action i was done with this but problem is that when i m  on next view which is coming after flip there is one button and using that button i want to go another view button this button won't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read that [Apple documentation article on Modal View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1) which explains everything you are asking there. Basically what you need to do on your logout view is to call :

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

By calling this, the *back* (left-to-right) flip animation  will be done automatically :

> **UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal**
>
> When the view controller is presented, the current view initiates a horizontal 3D flip from right-to-left, resulting in the revealing of the new view as if it were on the back of the previous view. **On dismissal, the flip occurs from left-to-right, returning to the original view.**

Comment: thanx for reply any idea.. but it is not working... in viewdidunload method i dismissed the modelviewcontroller.

Comment: add code in your question, it is hard to imagine what you are trying to do :)

Comment: following is the button code using this i was performed flip action for next view. -(void)ClicOnLogout {
    LogOutViewController *logOut=[[LogOutViewController alloc]initwithnName:str];  
    logOut.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;  

    [self presentModalViewController:logOut animated:YES];  
}and this code for button which present on the view which appear after flip but it is not working -(void)ClickOnLoginHear
{
 LoginViewController *login=[[LoginViewController alloc]init];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:login animated:NO];
}

Comment: still not enough code... `ClickOnLoginHear` is called when/from where?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the popViewControllerAnimated method:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

or you can assign it to push it onto the navigation controllers stack:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: thanx for reply but i wan't flip effect